# Forwarding ports through OpenVPN server to local server (Ubuntu 20.04 x64)

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, openvpn, port-forwarding, vps

**The Goal**

Hello, I have run into quite a wall when it comes to figuring out my issue of forwarding ports through my remote VPS to my local home server. What I am trying to do is host a Counter Strike GO server for my buddies and I but have everyone (including myself) connect via a VPS located in Dallas TX which would in theory forward the requests via OpenVPN to my home server as that would equalize any ping advantage I would have over my friends on the east coast.

**The Ports and IPs**

27005 UDP outbound

27015 TCP and UDP inbound and outbound *Main port*

27020 UDP inbound and outbound

51840 UDP outbound

WAN VPS 45.58.xx.xx

VPN Gateway 10.8.0.1

VPN Client 10.8.0.2

**The Problem**

So now this seems like it should be a simple project and that is what I thought at first but upon scouring the web for other forum posts and trying many of them I have come up empty handed. My goal was to use `iptables` and below are the different combinations of commands I tried to run with no success in accomplishing my goal.

`sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d 10.8.0.2 -p tcp --dport 27015 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d 10.8.0.2 -p udp --dport 27015 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d 10.8.0.2 -p udp --dport 27020 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -d 10.8.0.2 -p tcp --dport 27015 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -d 10.8.0.2 -p udp --dport 27015 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -d 10.8.0.2 -p udp --dport 27020 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -d 10.8.0.2 -p udp --dport 27005 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -d 10.8.0.2 -p udp --dport 51840 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
```

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 45.58.xx.xx -p udp --dport 27005 -j DNAT --to-dest 10.8.0.2:27005
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 45.58.xx.xx -p tcp --dport 27015 -j DNAT --to-dest 10.8.0.2:27015
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 45.58.xx.xx -p udp --dport 27015 -j DNAT --to-dest 10.8.0.2:27015
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 45.58.xx.xx -p udp --dport 27020 -j DNAT --to-dest 10.8.0.2:27020

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.8.0.2 -p tcp --dport 27015 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.8.0.2 -p udp --dport 27015 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.8.0.2 -p udp --dport 27020 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.8.0.2 -p udp --dport 27005 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.8.0.2 -p udp --dport 51840 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.1
```

Now, neither of those combinations of iptable entries worked as when I had the server running on my local server I was unable to view any service running on any of those ports or connect to the server via my CSGO client. Also, between the sets of commands I cleared the iptables and all of those commands were run with sudo and afterword `iptables-save` was run.

**More Info**

When I run the command `ip a` this is the dump I receive from the console.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/void
    inet 127.0.0.1/32 scope host venet0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 45.58.xx.xx/32 brd 45.58.xx.xx scope global venet0:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2602:ffc5:1f::xx:xxxx/128 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::2/128 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 10.8.0.1/24 brd 10.8.0.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fddd:1194:1194:1194::1/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2105:549d:51f6:9a16/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

One thing I noticed about the above dump is that I do not have `eth0` but rather my WAN is connected via `venet0`. I am not sure if that would make a difference.

Other than this port forwarding nonsense, I am able to connect to the VPN and I do have internet connectivity on my local server when I am connected.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**The Solution**

As it usually is, the simple solution is what is needed. In the end my problem revolved around Windows Firewall. For some reason it did not allow my CSGO server to communicate through the firewall.

All I did was open the firewall to my server exe and the `iptables` commands I used are as follows which I found from [linuxquestisons](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/iptable-port-forward-between-two-lan-interface-945719/):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface tun0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface venet0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i venet0 -m tcp --dport 27015 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2:27015
```

That's literally it. Thanks for reading my post and hopefully this helps someone else in the future.